# Why are Justin Trudeau and Benjamin Netanyahu meeting with Bollywood actors?

Tags: india, israel, foreign-policy, geopolitics, canada

Recently, Justin Trudeau and Benjamin Netanyahu met with Bollywood actors during their respective visits to India.

Given that these meetings won't persuade Bollywood to make movies in Israel or Canada, or contribute much to their already large economies, what political purpose do these meetings serve?

Citations:
Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu wooed Bollywood heavyweights in Mumbai on Thursday at "Shalom Bollywood", a high-profile official outreach programme by the Israeli government to improve its image abroad.

http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/01/benjamin-netanyahu-woos-india-bollywood-stars-180118185445791.html

Comment: Let me guess... those were actors that were very, very popular in India?

Comment: For Trudeau and Netanyahu, probably because they like their movies, and maybe some production or another could use a foreign actor to play a bad guy.  For the studios, it's a no-brainer, meeting heads of state is good press and free advertising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actors are celebrities.

1. Meeting with a celebrity is often more than enough to convince that celebrity's fans to feel more positively for you, since they take it as tacit or overt show of supporting you.
2. Separately, if you're a powerful person yourself, meeting with a celebrity will endear you to their fans because they see it as endorsing that celebrity.

Politics is a networking/perception game, and this plays to that aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

Modern politicians want to appear "hip" and "in tune" with the young
generation. Netanyahu meeting with Bollywood actors and taking a
*[selfie](https://www.ndtv.com/entertainment/benjamin-netanyahus-bollywood-selfie-with-amitabh-bachchan-aishwarya-and-other-stars-1802012)*
is part and parcel of that strategy:

> "I want all the Bollywood celebrities, producers and stars to join
> together for a selfie. Let a few hundred million people see the
> friendship," Mr Netanyahu said.
>
> "Will my Bollywood selfie beat @TheEllenShow Hollywood selfie at the
> Oscars? @SrBachchan @juniorbachchan @rajcheerfull @imbhandarkar
> @vivek_oberoi," PM Benjamin Netanyahu captioned the selfie.

The words starting with @ are tags which direct the reader to other
twitter feeds. I believe the more tags you use, the more visible your
post becomes to twitter readers. Netanyahu might be old (68), but he
is no geezer!

Justin Trudeau employed
[a similar strategy](http://www.news18.com/news/buzz/justin-trudeau-clearly-watches-too-much-bollywood-his-india-trip-proved-it-1668619.html). It
appears some twitterers thought it went a little overboard:

> Is it just me or is this choreographed cuteness all just a bit much
> now? Also FYI we Indians don’t dress like this every day sir, not
> even in Bollywood.

There is even a
[youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeMrX9QE1bE) from 2015
of him dancing Bhangra.

In addition to that,
[Bollywood is cautious](http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/chennai/chen-society/bollywood-is-cautious-with-politics/article6587808.ece)
when it comes to approaching political issues. Therefore meeting with
it is fairly safe. Only
[three actors](https://stepfeed.com/these-muslim-bollywood-actors-refused-to-meet-israeli-pm-benjamin-netanyahu-4324),
Shah Rukh Khan, Aamir Khan, and Salman Khan refused to meet with
Netanyahu in the Shalom Israel event.

The strategy is a double-edged sword. They want themselves
to appear cool and funny and their opponents
([The BDS Movement](http://www.middleeasteye.net/news/Netanyahu-faces-Indian-BDS-backlash-over-Bollywood-selfie-1564705089),
in Netanyahu's case) grumpy and boring. Why complain about
"cultural propaganda" when you can dance the night away? The risk is that they instead appear cheesy and fake.

Answer (score 0):

> Why Justin Trudeau/Benjamin Netanyahu in his Indian visit is meeting with Bollywood actors?
>
> Recently, Justin Trudeau and Benjamin Netanyahu during their Indian visit met with Bollywood actor.

It's the other way around.

Those actors were the ones who met those PMs.

> What political purpose does this meet serve?
>
> Given that just this meet won't persuade Bollywood to make movies in Israel or Canada and also it won't contribute much to their already large economy.

If you observe carefully, Muslims actors never met Netanyahu.

Other than that, there are no politics involved from the guests' sides.

Comment: Those actors were invited by the respective embassy in India

Comment: @Nikhil, citation needed.

Comment: Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu wooed Bollywood heavyweights in Mumbai on Thursday at "Shalom Bollywood", a high-profile official outreach programme by the Israeli government to improve its image abroad.

http://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/01/benjamin-netanyahu-woos-india-bollywood-stars-180118185445791.html

Comment: Another one: https://www.instagram.com/p/BfbZ1BUhrQB/

Comment: @Nikhil, why did you post the question then?

Comment: Cited sources have given some theory about it, but I was not convinced. So thought of seeking others opinion.